# How to inherit app dependency from module (Android)

Tags: java, android, aar

so i'm working on an app with a project structure similar to the one below

```
main app -
     libs - aarlib
module1
module2
```

With the structure above, one can easily see that main app has an aar file as a dependency and its added to the build.gradle file like this

```
compile (name: 'aarlib', ext: 'aar')
```

Now i want the modules in the project to inherit from the main app's aarlib file. How do i go about that?

In each module's.build file, i've tried the

```
compile (name: 'aarlib', ext: 'aar')
```

when i try the code above, i get a can't find file error. Is there a way to jump on folder or something of the sort in gradle.

Please note that i don't want to include the aar in the modules libs folder. Is there a way to go about this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

1. If module1 and module2 are not dependent, then I would advise creating another module where to put aar file and make all other modules dependent on it. If you put aar file in each lib folder, then you have a risk to have duplicated classes error unless you make that dependency as `provided`.
2. Another solution would be to put aar in local maven and reference it in all three projects. However, it will break builds for other people in the team unless they will deploy this aar to their local maven repo.
3. Another possible solution that I don't like at all. Replace in modules `compile (name: 'aarlib', ext: 'aar')` with `provided (name: '../app/aarlib', ext: 'aar')`

Comment: Thanks @Eugen  so in essence, modules can't add a parent's dependency? i'll have to use the local maven approach